# How to install pip for more than one python version

Tags: python3, pip, ubuntu-22.04

I have python3.8 and I have installed python3.7 on Ubuntu 22.04.

Also I have pip.

When I run `pip3 -V` or `pip -V` I got
`pip 22.2.2 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)`.

But when I run `python3.7 -m pip help install` I got `/usr/bin/python3.7: No module named pip` error. How can I make python3.7 to see `pip` installation.